# What the code '_T = TypeVar('_T')' means in a *.pyi file?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, pyi

I'm new to Python annotation (type hints). I noticed that many of the class definitions in `pyi` files inherit to `Generic[_T]`, and `_T = TypeVar('_T')`.

I am confused, what does the `_T` mean here？

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T')

class Base(Generic[_T]): pass
```

Comment: _ is just means that that variable is protected type.

Comment: python does not support protections on variables like java but it is convention to use _ for developer convention

Answer (score 20):

I recommend reading through the entire [built-in typing module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing).

---

### [typing.TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)

#### Basic Usage

Specifically, [**typing.TypeVar**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) is used to specify that multiple possible types are allowed. If no specific types are specified, then any type is valid.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')            # <-- 'T' can be any type
A = TypeVar('A', str, int)  # <-- 'A' will be either str or int
```

But, if **T** can be any type, then why create a [**typing.TypeVar**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) like that, when you could just use [**typing.Any**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) for the type hint?

The reason is so you can ensure that particular input and output arguments have the same type, like in the following examples.

#### A Dict Lookup Example

```
from typing import TypeVar, Dict
Key = TypeVar('Key')
Value = TypeVar('Value')

def lookup(input_dict: Dict[Key, Value], key_to_lookup: Key) -> Value:
    return input_dict[key_to_loopup]
```

This appears to be a trivial example at first, but these annotations require that the types of the keys in input dictionary are the same as the `key_to_lookup` argument, and that the type of the output matches the type of the values in the dict as well.

The keys and values as a whole could be different types, and for any particular call to this function, they could be different (because Key and Value do not restrict the types), but for a given call, the keys of the dict must match the type of the lookup key, and the same for the values and the return type.

#### An Addition Example

If you create a new TypeVar and limit the types to float and int:

```py
B = TypeVar('B', float, int)

def add_x_and_y(x: B, y: B) -> B:
    return x + y
```

This function requires that x and y either both be float, or both be int, and the same type must be returned. If x were a float and y were an int, the type checking should fail.

---

### [typing.Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic)

I'm a little more sketchy on this one, but the [typing.Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) (links to the official docs) Abstract Base Class (ABC) allows setting up a Class that has a defined type hint. They have a good example in the linked docs.

In this case they are creating a completely generic type class. If I understand correctly, this allows using `Base[AnyName]` as a type hint elsewhere in the code and then one can reuse `AnyName` to represent the same type elsewhere within the same definition (i.e. within the same code scope).

I suppose this would be useful to avoid having to use `TypeVar` repeatedly, you can basically create new TypeVars at will by just using the Base class as a type hint, as long as you just need it for the scope of that local definition.

Comment: Does the first argument 'B' always have to match the variable name B? This is the case in every example I've seen but I haven't seen an explanation as to why this has to be the case, or whether it has to be the case at all.

Comment: [Found the answer, yes it should be the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604980/difference-between-output-variable-and-first-argument-in-pythons-typevar)