# difference between output variable and first argument in Python's TypeVar

Tags: python

I'm looking at the documentation for Python TypeVar and I can't figure out what the first argument (or perhaps assignment variable) means.

From 3.8 documentation:

```
A = TypeVar('A', str, bytes)  # Must be str or bytes

def longest(x: A, y: A) -> A:
    """Return the longest of two strings."""
    return x if len(x) >= len(y) else y
```

My question is, what do the A's mean below?

```
 A = TypeVar('A', str, bytes)
```

Every example I've seen has the variable name the same as the first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, yes, it must be the variable name. From [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#generics):

> The argument to TypeVar() must be a string equal to the variable name
>   to which it is assigned. Type variables must not be redefined.

Answer (score 2):

It is the name that is being setted to `.__name__` of the TypeVar instance, see [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/typing.py#L586). This makes the object that is assigned to variable `A`, has the name `"A"`. The source code is pretty self explanatory